# Wordpress - I would like to let the visitors in my site choose between mobile responsive or desktop style mode

Tags: css, wordpress, responsive-design

I have wordpress theme and I would like to add a popup when visitor get into my website from mobile and ask him if he wants to see the site mobile mode or desktop mode.

How can i make it? 
Do i need 2 different sites or can I make it on the same site with 2 CSSs files?

I would like to hear any other suggestion. Thank you

Comment: Go read up on _CSS Media Queries_. This doesn’t need a popup nor “asking” the user.

Comment: With CSS Media Queries I can give the user to deside which css he style he wants to see?

Comment: No, the browser makes that decision automatically.

Comment: This can be done and has been done, just not simply if you are new to php. Take a look at http://dev.eyedea.eu/samples/styleswitch-php/, which is pure php and not wordpress, but it will be a good stating point. You will have to edit your theme or create a plugin. I have done this a few years back for a regular php site.

Answer (score -1):

I am using WPtouch Mobile plugin. It automatically enables mobile theme for mobile visitors. Here is the plugin which helps you to create pop up for your visitors.  wordpress.https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-popup/ .